# Wine installation problem

Tags: 12.04, installation, software-center

When I try to install Wine I get this fault

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine1.5: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) but 1.16.1.2ubuntu7 is to be installed
         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.5-i386 (= 1.5.6-0ubuntu1~pulse17) but 1.5.6-0ubuntu1~pulse17 is to be installed
```

Comment: Just using **Ubuntu 12.04** and **Software Centre**, you would have loaded **wine 1.4-0ubuntu4**.  Where did you find **wine1.5**, and how did you install it?

Comment: 1.5 is available from the official ppa.  it works fine for me.  i suspect pinned packages

Answer (score 1):

kamalesh. It seems that there's something wrong your software sources. Do you have PPA enabled on your machine? If so, try to do a ppa-purge to disable them and restore your repos to the orginal state. Please post your sources.list:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and I'll try to help you. Thank you.

Zhaofeng

Comment: I have the official ppa working fine here with wine 1.5.  Just a note.

Comment: This answer feels like it is asking for Debugging Details more than it is providing resolving advice.  Should it be transferred to a comment under the question?

Answer (score 1):

After downloading Wine 1.5.2 I had the same problem, but took the "safe" route.  I opened Synaptic Package Manager and typed in each of the dependencies (one at a time, checking the box and then "Install").  It cleaned up the whole mess including autoconfiguration.